# SQL compare two rows in a table to find how many values are different

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table for storing user data:

e.g.

```
TABLE: users
COLUMNS:
...
maritalStatus (INT)   - FK
gender        (CHAR)
occupation    (INT)   - FK
...
```

Now I want to compare two users in this table to see how many columns match for any two given users (say user X &  user Y)

I am doing it via mySQL Stored Procedures by getting each value separately and then comparing them

e.g.

```
    SELECT maritalStatus from users where userID = X INTO myVar1;
    SELECT maritalStatus from users where userID = Y INTO myVar2;

    IF myVar1 = myVar2 THEN

    ...

    END IF;
```

Is there a shorter way using an SQL query where I can compare two rows in a table and see 
which columns are different? I dont need to know how much different they actually are, just
need to know if they contain the same value. Also I will only be comparing selected columns, 
not every column in the user table.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will select the number of columns that are **not** the same for user `x` and user `y`:

```
SELECT ( u1.martialStatus <> u2.martialStatus )
     + ( u1.gender        <> u2.gender        )
     + ( u1.occupation    <> u2.occupation    )
FROM
  users u1,
  users u2
WHERE u1.id = x
  AND u2.id = y
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this:

```
select 

   -- add other columns as needed
   (a.lastname,a.gender) 
=  (b.lastname,a.gender) as similar,


  a.lastname as a_lastname,
  a.firstname as a_firstname,
  a.age as a_age,

  'x' as x,

  b.lastname as b_lastname,
  b.firstname as b_firstname,
  b.age as b_age



from person a
cross join person b
where a.id = 1 and b.id = 2
```

Output:

```
SIMILAR A_LASTNAME A_FIRSTNAME A_AGE X B_LASTNAME B_FIRSTNAME B_AGE
1       Lennon     John        40    x Lennon     Julian      15
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/840a1/2

Answer (score 1):

Just a continued example of Peter Langs suggestion in PHP:

```
$arr_cols   = array('martialStatus', 'gender', 'occupation');
$arr_where = array();
$arr_select = array();
foreach($arr_cols as $h) {

    $arr_having[] = "compare_{$h}";
    $arr_select[] = "(u1.{$h} != u2.{$h}) AS compare_{$h}";

}

$str_having  = implode(' + ', $arr_where);
$str_select = implode(', ', $arr_where);

$query = mysql_query("
SELECT {$str_select}
FROM users AS u1, users AS u2
WHERE u1.userid = {$int_userid_1} AND u2.userid = {$int_userid_2}
HAVING {$str_having} > 0
");

/* Having case can be removed if you need the row regardless. */

/* Afterwards you check these values: */

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
foreach($arr_cols as $h)
    if ($row["compare_{$h}"])
         echo "Found difference in column {$h}!";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of users with the same columns using `group by`:

```
select  u1.maritalStatus
,       u1.gender
,       u1.occupation
,       count(*)
from    users u1
group by
        u1.maritalStatus
,       u1.gender
,       u1.occupation
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - however I need a query that specifically compares two given users. Your query simply lists the no. of users with a specific value.

I would need to also specify which users I am comparing with a WHERE clause (e.g. WHERE userid = 87 AND userid = 88) - hope thats clear.

Comment: Well basicly the relevant row would give the value 2 if both users have the same maritalStatus, gender, occupation. You could add a `WHERE u1.user_id IN (id1, id2)` and see if there's one row with the value 2 returned.

Comment: @SydneyBoy: I think Peter Lang's answer might be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think, this may help someone. 
Objective: To find rows with same name and update new records date with the old record. This could be a condition where you will have to duplicate news item for different countryand keep the same date as original.

```css
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `locale` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'en',
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` text,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thumb` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `excerpt` text,
  `meta_title` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_description` varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
  `other_meta_tags` text,
  `read_count` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `revised` text,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `t` (`id`, `locale`, `title`, `slug`, `body`, `image`, `thumb`, `slug_title`, `excerpt`, `meta_title`, `meta_description`, `other_meta_tags`, `read_count`, `status`, `revised`, `created`, `modified`)
VALUES
 (2, 'en', 'A title once again', '/news/title-one-again', 'And the article body follows.', '/uploads/2014/11/telecommunications100x100.jpg', NULL, NULL, NULL, '', '', NULL, 0, 'Draft', NULL, '2014-09-22 12:26:17', '2014-10-23 10:13:21'),
 (3, 'en', 'A title once again', '/news/title-strikes-back', 'This is really exciting! Not.', '/uploads/2014/11/telecommunications100x100.jpg', NULL, NULL, NULL, '', '', NULL, 0, 'Unpublished', NULL, '2014-09-23 12:26:17', '2014-10-31 11:12:55'),
 (4, 'en_GB', 'test', '/news/test', 'test', '/uploads/2014/11/telecommunications100x100.jpg', NULL, NULL, NULL, '', '', NULL, 0, 'Published', NULL, '2014-10-23 10:14:30', '2014-10-23 10:14:30');


update t join
       t t2
       on t.title = t2.title 
    set t2.created = t.created
    where t.title = t2.title ;
```

update t join
       t t2
       on t.title = t2.title 
    set t2.created = t.created
    where t.title = t2.title ;

Answer (score 0):

In the event another Magento developer finds their way here, a specific use for this Q/A is to compare two address entries in a table. "Magento 1" will put the same address in twice with the only differences being the key `entity_id` column and `address_type` column ( billing or shipping ).

Already knowing the order's `entity_id`, use this to get the billing and shipping address IDs associated with the order: 
`SELECT entity_id FROM sales_flat_order_address WHERE parent_id = 3137;`

Then to see if they differ for that order:

```
SELECT a1.parent_id AS 'order_id'
,  ( a1.street    <> a2.street    )
 + ( a1.city      <> a2.city      )
 + ( a1.postcode  <> a2.postcode  )
 + ( a1.region_id <> a2.region_id )
 AS 'diffs'
FROM
  sales_flat_order_address a1,
  sales_flat_order_address a2
WHERE a1.entity_id = 6273
  AND a2.entity_id = 6274
;
```

Gives the output:

```
+----------+-------+
| order_id | diffs |
+----------+-------+
|     3137 |     0 |
+----------+-------+
```

**It would be fantastic if there was a way to do this en masse.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out which columns have different values in two rows of a table, you can use the following query:

```
SET @table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
SET @primary_column_name = 'PRIMARY_COLUMN_NAME';
SET @row1_id = '1234';
SET @row2_id = '1111';


SELECT CONCAT(
    "SELECT ",
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(" (CASE WHEN t1.", column_name, " != t2.", column_name ," THEN t1.", column_name, " ELSE '-' END) AS ", column_name ,"\n") AS all_column_names 
                FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = @table_name AND table_schema = DATABASE()
    ), " FROM ",@table_name," AS t1 INNER JOIN Artiklar AS t2 ON(t1.",@primary_column_name," = '",@row1_id,"' AND t2.",@primary_column_name," = '",@row2_id,"')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ",
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(" (CASE WHEN t1.", column_name, " != t2.", column_name ," THEN t2.", column_name, " ELSE '-' END) AS ", column_name ,"\n") AS all_column_names 
                FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = @table_name AND table_schema = DATABASE()
    ), " FROM ",@table_name," AS t1 INNER JOIN Artiklar AS t2 ON(t1.",@primary_column_name," = '",@row1_id,"' AND t2.",@primary_column_name," = '",@row2_id,"')
")
```

It will give you a new SQL query that you can run to see which columns have different values between the two rows.